# Can I ever lose committed work, in git?

Tags: git

Is it ever possible to lose work in git? Let's assume all my work is committed, and I didn't run `git gc`.
If I try some "funky command" ( NOT `rm -rf .git` ), and something strange happens to my project, could I recover from it?
Is there something in particular I should avoid doing? Or clone the repository elsewhere before attempting it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most errors you make with git can be recovered through the use of the [reflog](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reflog.html). One exception to this is deleting your branch, because of course that deletes the associated reflog. If that happens you may still be able to find the branch again by looking at the reflog of HEAD, but if you haven't checked the branch out in a while (or never checked out the latest tip of the branch) then it won't be there. But even then, you can try using `git fsck --lost-found` to find your dangling commits, and trawl through them to find likely candidates for the branch tip.

As you already indicated, if you run something which corrupts the `.git` directory, then all bets are off.

Comment: If you realize immediately after deleting a branch, that you didn't mean to delete it, just look at the output from `git branch -d`: "Deleted branch branchname (was 2cbda72)"